# Why does the compiler not infer the concrete type of an associated type of an impl trait return value?

Tags: rust, traits, type-inference

I have a trait with an associated type:

```
pub trait Speak {
    type Error;
    fn speak(&self) -> Result<String, Self::Error>;
}
```

An implementation of that trait:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Dog;

impl Speak for Dog {
    type Error = ();
    fn speak(&self) -> Result<String, Self::Error> {
        Ok("woof".to_string())
    }
}
```

And a function returning an instance of that implementation:

```
pub fn speaker() -> impl Speak {
    Dog::default()
}
```

I know that in this example I could just use `Dog` as the return type, but in my actual code I have to use `impl Speak` instead (the above function is in fact generated by a macro).

As I understand it, the `impl Trait` notation lets the compiler figure out which concrete type is actually returned, so I would expect the following function to compile correctly because `speaker()` returns a `Dog` and that `Dog::Error` is the type `()`:

```
fn test() -> Result<String, ()> {
    speaker().speak()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=62b2d039a254f6a5f49b330933a98849)

Instead, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:21:5
   |
20 | fn test() -> Result<String, ()> {
   |              ------------------ expected `std::result::Result<std::string::String, ()>` because of return type
21 |     speaker().speak()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, ()>`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, <impl Speak as Speak>::Error>`
```

It is as if the compiler could not (at this point) infer the return type of the `speaker` function.

Who is missing something something, the compiler or myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-> impl Speak<Error = ()>` as the return type of `speaker()`.

The problem is that the compiler needs, from the signature alone, enough information that the caller can actually use the function. If you just return `impl Speak`, then the compiler knows that `speak()` returns a `Result<String, ???>` - the error type isn't known, and thus the compiler issues an error.

The compiler cannot infer anything here. It cannot infer the error type from the call site, because `impl Trait` in return position doesn't allow inference from the call site. It cannot infer the error type from the implementation, because that would mean whether the caller type-checks depends on the implementation, and that's not how `impl Trait` works. The caller must always type-check in presence of only the information of the signature; the concrete type is only plugged in after that.

Comment: You wrote: "It cannot infer the type from the implementation". Really? When "impl Trait" was introduced, I understood that it allowed you to avoid using a Trait object, so I assumed that the actual type was resolved at compile time... Hence my expectation that the compiler would correctly infer the type.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine The actual type is resolved at compile time, but *after type checking*. The callers of `speaker()` have to typecheck solely based on the information given in the signature, i.e. `impl Speak` without information on the error type.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then. Thanks.

Comment: Also, of course I could write "-> Speak<Error = ()>", or even "-> Dog" for that matter. But as I (tried to) explain in my question, this is not an option in my actual code, because the 'speaker' function is generated by macro, and that macro has no information about the actual type... I guess I have to live with that, or find a way to provide that info to the macro, somehow.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine Maybe file a new question with a more realistic reduction of your root problem? There is some weirdness in the design you present, like on one hand you don't want the function to specify the result type, on the other you want the caller to be able to assume it.

Answer (score 2):

You are.

You never specified the associated `Error` type, so you're not allowed to assume anything about it.  Even if it really is `()`, the compiler won't allow you to use that knowledge.  To solve this, just specify what `Error` is:

```
pub fn speaker() -> impl Speak<Error = ()> {
    Dog::default()
}
```

Comment: Please see my 3rd comment to @sebasitan-redl above.