# Impl trait with generic associated type in return position causes lifetime error

Tags: rust

I need to store a `fn(I) -> O` (where `I` & `O` can be references) in a `'static` struct. `O` needs to be a trait with an `'static` generic associated type, that associated type is also stored in the struct. Neither `I` nor `O` itself get stored inside of the struct, so their lifetime shouldn't matter. But the compiler is still complaining about `I` not living long enough.

```rust
trait IntoState {
    type State: 'static;

    fn into_state(self) -> Self::State;
}

impl IntoState for &str {
    type State = String;

    fn into_state(self) -> Self::State {
        self.to_string()
    }
}

struct Container<F, S> {
    func: F,
    state: S,
}

impl<I, O> Container<fn(I) -> O, O::State>
where
    O: IntoState,
{
    fn new(input: I, func: fn(I) -> O) -> Self {
        // I & O lives only in the next line of code. O gets converted into
        // a `'static` (`String`), that is stored in `Container`.
        let state = func(input).into_state();
        Container { func, state }
    }
}

fn map(i: &str) -> impl '_ + IntoState {
    i
}

fn main() {
    let _ = {
        // create a temporary value
        let s = "foo".to_string();

        // the temporary actually only needs to live in `new`. It is
        // never stored in `Container`.
        Container::new(s.as_str(), map)
        // ERR:        ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
    };
    // ERR: `s` dropped here while still borrowed
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfdcc654ba061dd660f6eb466a34b086)

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the associated generic type, if i remove it (inserting `String` as return type) it starts to work. [playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7618aa9f84b952480f3164a966c2f4fa). But i it to be generic for my application logic.

Comment: Should i update the title & description to better reflect the issue (not storing the fn is the problem here, but the `IntoState` trait/"missing" generic type) ?

Comment: I would update it in a way that it is not about the static lifetime, but it is still reflecting the compiler's error message (because people will search for that misleading stuff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the compiler's error message is misleading, what it actually requires is an explicitly defined associated type:

```rust
fn map(i: &str) -> impl '_ + IntoState<State = String> {
    i
}
```

The excellent answer given to the quesion: [Why does the compiler not infer the concrete type of an associated type of an impl trait return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831644/2188562) provides enough information on why this is actually needed.

See also [Rust issue #42940 - impl-trait return type is bounded by all input type parameters, even when unnecessary](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42940)

You can use a generic type parameter instead of returning an `impl` in which case you don't have to specify the associated type:

```rust
fn map<T: IntoState>(i: T) -> T {
    i
}
```

Comment: hmm, but in my case i only need `IntoState::State` to be `'static`, i don't need the actual type. In my actual code im accessing state only through the "IntoState" trait (which obviously knows the associated type), never directly. But i guess it's still not enough info for the compiler?!

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative `map` implementation which does not require you to define the associated type.

Comment: There is no reason why the compiler should need the exact type. All it needs to know is that `State` has static lifetime, and this is already known from the trait definition. This looks like a compiler shortcoming to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it sure does look like one!

Comment: The version in the update works in this example, but sometimes you actually want to use an existential type instead. You can use a hack like `impl IntoState<State = impl Any + 'static>` or similar, but this seems wrong as well.

Comment: @SvenMarnach can you provide an example where only the former version is acceptable and the latter (updated) one is not?

Comment: @PeterVaro If you make `T` a type parameter, it can be freely chosen by the _caller_ of the `map()` function. Sometimes you want the return type to be chosen by the function itself, without explicitly naming it, which is the whole point of `impl Trait` in return type position. And example would be `fn map(_: i32) -> impl IntoState { "abc" }`, but you don't want to guarantee the actual return type in the interface.

Comment: I believe I found the right GitHub issue for this problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42940

Comment: @SvenMarnach fair enough, that makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the GH ref!

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is not a bug. Returning a `T: IntoState` (universally quantified) is completely different from returning an `impl IntoState` (existentially quantified). In the first case the caller determines `T` and therefore the associated type is known to any caller. In the second case, the caller does not know which implementation of the trait it is going to get and therefore needs to know the associated types in order to do anything with it.

Comment: @PeterHall I'm not completely sure I understand your comment. It's completely fine to return `impl IntoState` without specifying the associated type. The caller will not be able to make any assumptions about the associated type except for the bounds of the associated type in the trait definition, but in principle it is allowed to omit the associated type. In this specific case, however, the returned type will be parametrized by the lifetime of the `&str` argument to `map()`, so the associated type will also contain that lifetime in spite of being declared `'static` in the trait definition.

Comment: I do consider this a shortcoming of the compiler (I won't get into a discussion whether it should be called a "bug"). The fact that this lifetime is captured in the _associated type_ of the existential return type is rather unexpected. I can understand why it is implemented in the compiler in this way, but from the viewpoint of a software developer writing Rust code, this behaviour does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is still some confusion about what exactly is going on here, so I'll try to destil my comments into a short answer.

The problem here is the prototype of the function `map()`:

```
fn map(i: &str) -> impl '_ + IntoState
```

This specifies that the return type of `map()` is *some* type implementing `IntoState`, with an unspecified associated type `State`. The return type has a lifetime parameter with the lifetime of the argument `i`; let's call that lifetime `'a`, and the full return type `T<'a>`. The associated type `State` of this return type now is `<T<'a> as IntoState>::State`, which is parametrized by `'a`. The compiler is currently not able to eliminate this lifetime parameter from the assoicated type, in spite of the `'static` declaration in the trait definition. By explicitly specifying the associated type as `String`, the compiler will simply use the explicitly specified type `String` instead of `<T<'a> as IntoState>::State`, so the lifetime parameter is gone, and we don't get an error anymore.

This compiler shortcoming is discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42940).