# "borrowed value does not live long enough" with a generic function that returns impl trait

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

I get an unexpected error from this Rust code:

```rust
struct Container<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

trait Reply {}
impl Reply for i32 {}

fn json<T>(_val: &T) -> impl Reply {
    3
}

fn f() -> impl Reply {
    let i = 123;
    let a = Container { x: &i };
    json(&a)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f002469f30f1a050100c76b25fe9472e)

The error is:

```
error[E0597]: `i` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:14:28
   |
12 | fn f() -> impl Reply {
   |           ---------- opaque type requires that `i` is borrowed for `'static`
13 |     let i = 123;
14 |     let a = Container { x: &i };
   |                            ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
15 |     json(&a)
16 | }
   | - `i` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why?

If I change the declaration of `json()` to either of these versions, the code compiles:

```rust
fn json(val: &Container) -> impl Reply
```

```rust
fn json<T>(val: &T) -> i32
```

It is only when there is both a type parameter and a returned trait object that the compiler rejects the code.

This is a reduction from a real issue we had with `warp::reply::json()`, but I would prefer to understand it in general.

Comment: I've looked at the first 20 hits for "borrowed value does not live long enough" on Stack Overflow but those didn't help. I didn't check the rest, sorry.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Impl trait with generic associated type in return position causes lifetime error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56636442/155423), especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636442/impl-trait-with-generic-associated-type-in-return-position-causes-lifetime-error?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment99848978_56637140). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks! It's certainly more relevant than what I have seen before. There are a bunch of differences, but it could be that both cases rest on the same underlying issue. I'm reading through the references in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

When the arguments and the return type of a function are generic, the Rust compiler assumes that the return type could, potentially, borrow the arguments. That's why it assumes that `f()` returns a value referencing the local variable `i`.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this is desired, because someone could implement `Reply` for a type where this would be problematic.

EDIT: This doesn't work because of a bug. It has already been reported on GitHub.

Comment: *the Rust compiler assumes that the return type could, potentially, borrow the arguments* — please enhance your answer to explain why `-> impl Reply + 'static` doesn't work.

Comment: I tried implementing a function that returns such a Reply but failed! Haha! Yeah, that doesn't prove anything. Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: One more thing though that I forgot to mention in the question. This only fails to compile when Container contains a borrow. If it contains a plain i32, it works. Why does the compile not worry that Reply could hold a reference to `a`? Why only worry about `i`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielDarabos that's interesting. However, it only fails if the borrow references a local variable: `let a = Container { x: &123 }` works.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't know, maybe someone who knows more about how the compiler works can answer this. Maybe this is indeed a bug.

Comment: @Aloso that's covered by [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)

Comment: There's *already* an [issue filed on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56636442/155423). It was linked in the comments on the original question here.

Answer (score 1):

Four years later, we have an in-depth answer: [Analysis of Rust issue #42940](https://hackmd.io/83sY9XQjSiK79QdnqK0F3Q)

I think the key part is this:

> The *value* returned by `test` does *not* reference any data owned by the current function.  The error message is just wrong about that.
>
> However, the *type* returned by `test` *does* reference a lifetime that's only valid within the current function.  That's the real problem here.