# How can I add extension methods to a trait with associated types lying in a different crate?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to add an extension method to a trait in a different crate.
This trait has an associated type specified on it.

```
pub trait Test<W> {
    type Error;

    fn do_sth(&mut self) -> Result<W, Self::Error>;
}
```

Why is it not possible to add a method that is using the associated type `Error`?

```
impl dyn Test<u8> {
    fn use_do_sth(&mut self) -> Result<u8: Self::Error> {
        self.do_sth()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d387172a01205a901efc7e88aeb135a)

Comment: Related: [Why does the compiler not infer the concrete type of an associated type of an impl trait return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52831488/3650362)

Comment: I'm curious what is the use-case to implement something directly on the trait object? You won't be able to extend the external trait this way (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb1566c65f74669d6ae45019b33fff72), and if this is your own trait, isn't it better to add methods on it?

Comment: @Cerberus It is not my own trait it is an external trait. The real problem is that have a struct wich contains this trait as an element. Now I need a helper_method which is only using this element. But because the helper_method is part of the struct and not the trait, I can‘t mut borrow another element while calling the helper_method. (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e764604ea3a4609018c655291ccf3e7)

Comment: You need to add this helper_method, it is your own code? Do you control the struct?

Comment: @Cerberus I don‘t really need the helper_method, I could also copy the code. But I thought there has to be a way to do this. And yes I control the struct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you need to add a method to the external type, the only option is to use *extension traits*. It means that you define your own trait, with whatever methods you need, and implement it for the types you need.

When you need to add a method to all types implementing some external trait, you can use the same pattern, but instead of listing the types directly, just use the trait bound:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

// This is an extension trait.
// You can force all its implementors to implement also some external trait,
// so that two trait bounds essentially collapse into one.
trait HelperTrait: Debug {
    fn helper_method(&mut self);
}

// And this is the "blanket" implementation,
// covering all the types necessary.
impl<T> HelperTrait for T where T: Debug {
    fn helper_method(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=209398bdad300776bf40d3b5badc601e])

The same idea could be applied to any external trait, as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the following?

```
impl<E> dyn Test<u8, Error = E> {
    fn use_do_sth(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E> {
        self.do_sth()
    }
}
```

I came up with this following the compiler's hint that "the value of the associated type `Error` must be specified".